# Storing iso8601 string stored in ActiveRecord as string or datetime?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I'm trying to write a schema for an ActiveRecord object.

I've decided to use iso8601 format throughout my application, including for external api requests.

Should the column be a `string` or `datetime`?

Is there any performance impact or distinction between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the date in the database as a `date` or `datetime` means you can use the date functions like comparing dates in the database. And it gives you the freedom to present the date in whichever format you choose, making it easy to do so if the formatting requirements change in the future, without having to touch the database.

Whereas storing the date in the database as a string removes all these advantages. You no longer can use database date functions. Plus, If you decide to use another format (maybe in a newer version of the API or for mobile apps... etc), you will need to parse the string back into a date/datetime object, which is not very appealing to do.

**As a general good practice: the way you store data should be agnostic to the way you present it, when possible.**

Comment: Wise advice. Your database offers data types for a reason; use them where wisely designed (some databases have poor or faulty handling of date-time values). The [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats are primarily aimed at serializing date-time values to text for data exchange with a side-benefit of being human-readable to assist with debugging and logging. For presentation to users, adjust into expected time zone and localize the format of displayed text.

Comment: So, pertaining to Rails and Ruby. I should just stick with the regular `Time` object and save it as :datetime, rather than doing .iso8601 on it and saving as :datetime?